# T-SQL not executing 2nd part of WHERE clause SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, where-clause

I have a SSRS report which runs from a stored procedure. I've got 2 parameters that must be chosen. My first parameter works perfectly, but when the 2nd parameter is chosen (Rep) it gets ignored by the report and returns all the Reps.

```
@Town Varchar(100)
,@Rep Varchar(100)

    select 
    a.Customer
    ,a.CustName
    ,a.Rep
    ,a.Town
    ,a.Qty
    ,a.SalesType
    ,b.Qty1
    ,c.Qty2
    ......
    from #1 a
    left join #2 b
    on a.Rep = b.Rep
    and a.Town = b.Town
    and a.Customer = b.Customer
    and a.SalesType = b.SalesType
    left join #3 c
    ..........
    WHERE ('ALL' IN (@Town))    OR     (a.Town IN (@Town)) 
    and ('ALL' IN (@Rep))    OR     (a.Rep IN (@Rep))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing here, but I am assuming you want the clauses for `@Town` and `@Rep` to be evaluates as a group each. To do so:

```
WHERE ('ALL' IN (@Town)    OR     a.Town IN (@Town)) 
and ('ALL' IN (@Rep)    OR     a.Rep IN (@Rep))
```

As you have it, since each clause is stand alone, you will get short circuit behavior.